# Range within range of certain size?

Tags: java, c#, spring, math, range

Say I have a range of 1 to 1000. How would I get a random sub-range within that range that does not exceed a size of x?

I have tried the following:

```
int newMin = getRandomInt(1,1000);
newMax = newMin + rangeSize;
```

But that fails because it could possibly go over the max range.

So if there is a start range 1 to 1000 and the subrange size is specified as size 100, the new range could be 200-300.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: please elaborate it more.

Comment: added additional info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try something like:

```
int newMin = getRandomInt(1,1000),
newMax = getRandomInt(newMin, 1000);
```

Your Range would be from newMin to newMax.

**Edit:** So it sounds like we have something called rangeSize. The above answer does not guarantee to get a new sub-range with the exact rangeSize. So here is the edited code:

```
int newMin = getRandomInt(1, 1000 - rangeSize),
newMax = newMin + rangeSize;
```

Comment: Close but not quite. The subrange has to be exactly the size specified.

Comment: Oh. Sorry! Your question is not so clear! Let me edit my response!

Comment: Apologies added another example :)

Comment: Answered! Hope it helps!

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, ty =)

Comment: Wouldn't `int newMin = getRandomInt(1, 1000 - rangeSize + 1), newMax = newMin + rangeSize - 1;`, e.g. a `rangeSize` of `2` might result in `newMin = 42` and `newMax = 43` for a total of `2` values included?

Comment: @CoffeelsProgramming you can go for modules operator as well.

Comment: Can you please explain how it would be done using modulus?

Comment: @HABO: I think the question is not very clear on the constraints of the sub-range as well as the rangeSize (e.g. rangeSize from 0 -> max/1000, newMin can be equal to newMax?!). Therefore, my answer just gives him/her the basic idea of how to tackle such a problem.